# Strange behaviour of Array.reduce() with negation and sum

Tags: javascript, reduce

Data:

```
arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Code:

#### 1

```
!arr[0] + !arr[1] + !arr[2] + !arr[3] + !arr[4]
// 3, correct!
```

but ...

#### 2

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => (!a + !b));
// 1, bullshit?!
```

Question:
Why is **1**. and **2**. not the same? Makes no sense to me? How can I reduce() my array to give me the same as in **1**.

---

Update:

```
arr = [{test: 0}, {test: 0}, {test: 0}, {test: 1}, {test: 1}]
```

try1: (why doesnt this work?)

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a.test + !b.test, {test: 0});
// NaN

arr.reduce((a, b) => a.test + !b.test, 0);
//NaN
```

Comment: In `reduce` you are negating the cumulative sum (accumulator) each time

Comment: i understand!, but how can I solve this with reduce?

Comment: Change `!a` to `a` and add an `initialValue` of `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are negating the previous sum on each iteration so it will be treated as `1`(true)  or `0`(false).

It's working like:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|  callback   | accumulator | currentValue |        return value         |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| first call  |           0 |            0 | !0 + !0 = true + true = 2   |
| second call |           2 |            0 | !2 + !0 = false + true = 1  |
| third call  |           1 |            1 | !1 + !1 = false + false = 0 |
| fourth call |           0 |            1 | !0 + !1 = true + false = 1  |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

---

So set an initial value with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and negate the next value and add with the previous sum.

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a + !b, 0);
```

```js
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

console.log(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + !b, 0));
```

Right now it would work like :

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------------+
|  callback   | accumulator | currentValue |      return value      |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------------+
| first call  |           0 |            0 | 0 + !0 = 0 + true = 1  |
| second call |           1 |            0 | 1 + !0 = 1 + true = 2  |
| third call  |           2 |            0 | 2 + !0 = 2 + true = 3  |
| fourth call |           3 |            1 | 3 + !1 = 3 + false = 3 |
| fifth call  |           3 |            1 | 3 + !1 = 3 + flase = 3 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

---

**UPDATE :** With a nested object it would be like,

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a + !b.test, 0);
```

Comment: this works like a charm. Totally made a noob mistake there. Thanks also to @adiga.

Comment: can you look into my edit? I chose data that is more realistic. Really dont understand why this does not work. :-(

Comment: @AndreElrico :  `arr.reduce((a, b) => a + !b.test, 0);` , there isn't any property test for a number

Comment: s*** that hurts ... same mistake. I think I now got it! You are my hero sir.